# Run time error of DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm getting the error `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String in line 53`

The line is `var note = n.getValue(Note::class.java)`

I've been stuck on this error for awhile as I'm new enough to coding and I'm not sure what to do, any help is appreciated, thanks very much

```
package com.example.gearoidodonovan.books

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.renderscript.Sampler
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.add_note.view.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var mRef:DatabaseReference? = null
    var mNoteList:ArrayList<Note>?= null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        mRef = database.getReference("Notes")
        mNoteList = ArrayList()



        add_new_note.setOnClickListener {

            showDialogAddNote()


        }
    }

    override fun onStart(){
        super.onStart()
        mRef?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                for (n in p0!!.children) {
                    var note = n.getValue(Note::class.java)
                    mNoteList?.add(note!!)

                }

                val noteAdapter = NoteAdapter(applicationContext, mNoteList!!)
                note_list_view.adapter = noteAdapter

            }

        })

    }


    fun showDialogAddNote() {
        val alertBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_note, null)

        alertBuilder.setView(view)

        val alertDialog = alertBuilder.create()
        alertDialog.show()


        view.btnSaveNote.setOnClickListener {
            val title = view.etTitle.text.toString()
            val note = view.etNote.text.toString()

            if (title.isNotEmpty() && note.isNotEmpty()) {
                var id = mRef!!.push().key!! //reference 1

                var myNote = Note(id, title, note, getCurrentDate())
                mRef!!.child(id).setValue(myNote)
                alertDialog.dismiss()


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }


        }

    }

    fun getCurrentDate(): String{
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val mdformat = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE hh:mm a ")
        val strDate = mdformat.format(calendar.time)
        return strDate
    }
}
```

Here is my note class

```
package com.example.gearoidodonovan.books

import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude
import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue

class Note {
    var id:String?= null
    var title:String? = null
    var note:String?= null
    var timestamp: String? = null

    constructor(){

    }

    constructor(id: String, title: String, note: String, timestamp: String){
        this.id = id
        this.title = title
        this.note = note
        this.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because you have a field of type long in your firebase node which you are saving in String. make sure that data types are same as in firebase node and your data class.

I think most of the cases the id is of data type long, you can check that and change your data class of Note according to that

Comment: Thank you very much I got it working, one more question if you would be able to answer it, I have for eg Tim & Ed in the database and I add Brian instead of it looking like Tim & Ed & Brian it looks like Tim & Ed & Tim & Ed & Brian

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question and please accept my above answer as it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Order attributes of your `class note` as following

````
var id:String?= null
var note:long?= null
var timestamp: String? = null
var title:String? = null```
````